# Ipython Notebook suddenly Cannot start

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using Windows + Anaconda. After I typed

```
ipython notebook
```

in the Command Prompt, nothing happened! No error as the output, and ipython notebook never started. My Ipython Notebook worked fine last week, but suddenly it's not working. What could be wrong here?

Btw, the last thing I did with it was installing Pybrain and writing some code.

Comment: Very hard to diagnose; you may want to start by running the command from a different directory or re/un-setting your PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: Maybe you should try `jupyter notebook` in the command line? The ipython notebook project was renamed and split; it is possible that you've upgraded to the new version.